# Add css into li element when flag is true in AngularJs Ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want add "parimaryAccount" css class into li element when "IsPrimaryAccount" is true

```
<ul class="accountList" style="">
<li ng-repeat="accunt in CompanyInfo.Accounts" > {{accunt.AccountName}} </li>
</ul>
```

### Json format

```
 {
  "ArrayOfAccountNumber": {
    "-xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "-xmlns": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/PCX.Entities.Model",
    "script": { "-id": "tinyhippos-injected" },
    "AccountNumber": [
      {
        "ACNumber": "ACN1009TEST",
        "AccountName": "AC1009TEST-123453",
        "IsPrimaryAccount": "false" 
      },
      {
        "ACNumber": "ACAdidasAccount001",
        "AccountName": "Adidas Account1-112",
        "IsPrimaryAccount": "true" 
      } 
    ]
  }
}
```

Output should be like this

```
<li>Account 2</li>
<li>Account 3</li>
<li class="parimaryAccount"> Primary Account </li>
<li>Account 5</li>
<li>Account 6</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) like this

```
<li ng-repeat="accunt in CompanyInfo.Accounts" ng-class={ 'parimaryAccount': accunt.IsPrimaryAccount'> {{accunt.AccountName}} </li>
```

It evaluates the accunt.IsPrimaryAccount and apply the class if the boolean is true. (Watch typos! parimary, accunt...)

Answer (score -2):

You can use a filter, for example

```
angular.filter('primaryAccount', function () {
    return function(account){
        if(account === 'true'){
            return 'parimaryAccount'
        }
    }
});
```

then on you can write your li tag as

```
<li class="accunt.isPrimaryAccount | primaryAccount">accunt.AccountName</li>
```